# Unable to make a wired connect to internet after using Windows®

Tags: 14.04, networking, ethernet

As long as I don't use Windows® I can reliably connect, even after multiple reboots. However any time after I boot into Windows®, then if I want to use my wired ethernet connection in Linux, I must power down the computer AND remove the AC cord into the computer's power supply AND remove the ethernet cable into the computer for a few seconds. Only after I do this can I reboot into Linux and connect to the internet. Otherwise the system never connects although it constantly attempts to connect. This started about a month ago after a Linux update. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x86.  Using the same hardware, booting into Windows® and making a connection is never a problem.  Is this hardware or software?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may come from your router that your computer is connected to, [some people](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2192946) had issue while dual booting Windows and Ubuntu. Their workaround was to disable DHCP and manually assign the same IP address to Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Artyom.  I get the same LAN IP address assigned to the computer in either OS.  Also I just got a brand new router and the problem persists.  So I'm thinking it's a software problem, especially since it started happening right after a recent kernel update, without any hardware changes.